# Where are the standard Windows prompt commands files?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, dir

If I type `dir` in the command line, I guess it executes a `dir.exe` hidden somewhere in the system. Is there such a file? Where is it?

Comment: Technically, the file is `cmd.exe`, though it’s not really being executed; it already was. `;-)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Dir` is an internal command, like `cd`, `copy`, and `call`. This is simply a subroutine of the DOS interpreter that you're calling.

There are, however, *external* commands. These commonly reside in `C:\Windows\` `C:\Windows\System\` `C:\Windows\System32` and (if you have 64-bit windows) `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\`

However, external commands are not limited to these locations. External commands can be called from the  directory that you're working from. (in a newly started DOS shell on Windows 7, this would usually be `C:\Users\YourUsername\`). External commands from other directories can also be called, as long as the directory they're in are in your `PATH` environment variable. To see what directories are in your path, use `SET PATH`.

If you're going to be needing some utility from a directory, but will have to be traversing to other directories, you can add the folder of the utility to the `PATH` by using `SET PATH=%PATH%;DriveLetter:\Utility\Path\Here\`. This change only affects that DOS window.

I hope that's new and useful knowledge!

Answer (score 39):

**dir** is an **internal** MS-DOS command. Like the other internal commands, it is built into the file named **command.com**. Wikipedia has a page for the [list of DOS commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DOS_commands), and it says:

> The command interpreter for MS DOS
>   runs when no application programs are
>   running; after an application exits,
>   if the memory used for the command
>   interpreter was overwritten, MS DOS
>   will re-load the command interpreter
>   from disk storage. The command
>   interpreter is usually stored in a
>   file called "**COMMAND.COM**". Some
>   commands are built-into COMMAND.COM.
>   When the user types a line of text at
>   the operating system command prompt,
>   COMMAND.COM will parse the line, and
>   attempt to match a command name to a
>   built-in command or to the name of an
>   excecutable program file or batch file
>   on disk. If no match is found, an
>   error message is printed and the
>   command prompt is refreshed.
>
> Resident commands varied slightly
>   between revisions of MS DOS.
>   Typically, the functions **DIR** (list
>   directory), **ERASE** or **DEL** (erase a file
>   or directory), **COPY** (copy files), **DATE**
>   (display or set date), **TIME** (display
>   or set time), **CD** (change working
>   directory), **MD** (make a directory on
>   the current disk), **REN** (rename a file
>   or directory) and some others were
>   resident in COMMAND.COM.

To make my answer complete, the following is a list of MS-DOS internal and external commands. The internal commands reside in **COMMAND.COM**, which loads into memory when the computer system is started; these commands do not reside on disk. The external commands are files that do reside on disk and have an extension of **.COM**, **.EXE**, or **.BAT**. Both command types are executed from the MS-DOS prompt.

**Internal Commands:**

- BREAK
- CALL
- CHCP
- CHDIR(CD)
- CLS
- COPY
- CTTY
- DATE
- DEL(ERASE)
- DIR
- ECHO
- EXIT
- FOR
- GOTO
- IF
- MKDIR(MD)
- PATH
- PAUSE
- PROMPT
- REM
- RENAME(REN)
- RMDIR(RD)
- SET
- SHIFT
- TIME
- TYPE
- VER
- VERIFY
- VOL

**External Commands:**

- APPEND.EXE
- ASSIGN.COM
- ATTRIB.EXE
- BACKUP.EXE
- CHKDSK.EXE
- COMMAND.COM
- COMP.EXE
- DEBUG.EXE
- DISKCOMP.COM
- DISKCOPY.COM
- DOSKEY.COM
- DOSSHELL.COM
- EDIT.COM
- EDLIN.EXE
- EMM386.EXE
- EXE2BIN.EXE
- EXPAND.EXE
- FASTOPEN.EXE
- FC.EXE
- FDISK.EXE
- FORMAT.COM
- GRAFTABLE.COM
- GRAPHICS.COM
- HELP.EXE
- JOIN.EXE
- KEYB.COM
- LABEL.EXE
- MEM.EXE
- MIRROR.COM
- MODE.COM
- MORE.COM
- NLSFUNC.EXE
- PRINT.EXE
- QBASIC.EXE
- RECOVER.EXE
- REPLACE.EXE
- RESTORE.EXE
- SETVER.EXE
- SHARE.EXE
- SORT.EXE
- SUBST.EXE
- SYS.COM
- TREE.COM
- UNDELETE.EXE
- UNFORMAT.COM
- XCOPY.EXE

Reference: [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/71986/en-us)

*Nota bene:* The external commands reside in `C:\Windows\System32` assuming the root drive is `C:`.

Comment: A +1 for you if you address the OP's unstated part of the question with regard to where the *external* utilities reside. (It's a very good answer so far, by the way.)

Comment: +1 for an extensive list, but -1 for mixing MS-DOS and Windows command line shell.

Comment: @Dennis: You're welcome, and thank you for reminding that. @grawity: Can you please drop a few lines to clarify the confusion? I really don't see what part of my answer is lacking.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what grawity is aluding to but command.com was the name of the native DOS command-line shell. It was included in Windows 9x as that generation of windows was dependent upon DOS for certain services. Windows NT is not at all dependent upon DOS and so command.com is not present, the shell in NT is a native windows application called cmd.exe located in %WINDIR%\System32

Answer (score 10):

Most standard "DOS" commands are built into the command shell in Windows.  There isn't a `dir` or `cd` application

Answer (score 2):

For additional reference, here is a nice website that fairly good list of commands available for cmd.exe:

http://ss64.com/nt/

Answer (score 0):

Because of a bug in windows 10 i must go to C:\windows\system32 to type most of the commands so i do a little search in the directory for the tree commands and it was there and windows was calling it a MS-DOS app

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.